# display content before footer in report odoo

Tags: html, css, report, odoo, qweb

i'm trying to display a div "test" just before the div footer , i did this code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="mysale_report" inherit_id="report.external_layout_footer">
            <xpath expr="//div[@class='footer']" position="before">

                <div class ="test">
                   fix content  
                </div>

            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

but nothing show , in fact if i change 'before' by 'after' the div test appear inside the footer .
the question why i cant display it before footer . is there any way to display content just before the footer ?
and thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If are you using a Debian Jessie, you need to install manually the wkhtmltopdf library form [HERE](http://nightly.odoo.com/extra/), Because the version of wkhtmltopdf available in debian repositories does not support headers and footers.
If you do that before or you are using other OS, try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
    <template id="mysale_report" inherit_id="report.external_layout_footer">
        <xpath expr="//div[@class='footer']" position="replace">
            <div class="footer">

                <div class="test">
                    fix content  
                </div>

                <div class="text-center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
                <ul t-if="not company.custom_footer" class="list-inline">
                    <li t-if="company.phone">Phone: <span t-field="company.phone"/></li>
                    <li t-if="company.fax and company.phone">&amp;bull;</li>
                    <li t-if="company.fax">Fax: <span t-field="company.fax"/></li>
                    <li t-if="company.email">&amp;bull;</li>
                    <li t-if="company.email">Email: <span t-field="company.email"/></li>
                    <li t-if="company.website">&amp;bull;</li>
                    <li t-if="company.website">Website: <span t-field="company.website"/></li>
                 </ul>

                 <t t-if="company.custom_footer">
                     <span t-raw="company.rml_footer"/>
                 </t>

                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li>Page:</li>
                    <li><span class="page"/></li>
                    <li>/</li>
                    <li><span class="topage"/></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
           </div>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</data>
```

I hope this can help you!

Comment: ok but i dont want to replace div test inside the footer , i wana display it just before the footer :(

Comment: Did you try run the code above?, the traditional footer begin after`<div class="text-center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">` and I put your `<div class="test">` before, just give it a shot! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Hear we will also do some another way to add the our own custom header and footer we have no need to add the external and internal layout header and footer in our Qweb View file.

Just You have to add the

Directly access the header and footer class in our view file.

for header :

```
             <div class="header">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <img t-if="company.logo" t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % company.logo" style="max-height: 50px;"/>
                     </div>      
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 pull-right" style="font-size:7px;">
                         <t t-if="company.street" >
                            <span style="text-align:right;" t-esc="company.street" /><br/>
                         </t>
                         <t t-if="company.street2" >
                            <span style="text-align:right;" t-esc="company.street2" /><br/>
                         </t>
                          <t t-if="company.phone" >
                            <span style="text-align:right;" t-esc="company.phone" /><br/>
                         </t>
                         <t t-if="company.fax" >
                            <span style="text-align:right;" t-esc="company.fax" /><br/>
                         </t>
                          <t t-if="company.email" >
                            <span style="text-align:right;" t-esc="company.email" /><br/>
                         </t>
                          <t t-if="company.website" >
                            <span style="text-align:right;" t-esc="company.website" /><br/>
                         </t>
                         <t t-if="company.vat" >
                            <span  style="text-align:right;" t-esc="company.vat" /><br/>
                         </t>
                     </div>   
                </div>
            </div>
```

for footer :

```
 <div class="footer">
        <div class="text-center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>Page:</li>
                <li><span class="page"/></li>
                <li>/</li>
                <li><span class="topage"/></li>
            </ul>

     </div>
</div>
```

the code you have to add after the called the template of `report.html_container` and before the `page class` in Qweb View File.

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)